# How can (say) ns1.example.com be a name server of example.com?

Tags: dns, resolution

Clearly I don't know much about DNS, so bear with me on this issue, which has been puzzling me  me for a while.

Some WHOIS records show (say) ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com as name servers for example.com. Then how is the actual IP address found? Isn't this circular?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question probably belongs on Severfault rather than Stackoverflow, but for the explanation you should read about [glue records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records).

> Name servers in delegations are
>   identified by name, rather than by IP
>   address. This means that a resolving
>   name server must issue another DNS
>   request to find out the IP address of
>   the server to which it has been
>   referred. If the name given in the
>   delegation is a subdomain of the
>   domain for which the delegation is
>   being provided, there is a circular
>   dependency. In this case the
>   nameserver providing the delegation
>   must also provide one or more IP
>   addresses for the authoritative
>   nameserver mentioned in the
>   delegation. This information is called
>   glue. The delegating name server
>   provides this glue in the form of
>   records in the additional section of
>   the DNS response, and provides the
>   delegation in the answer section of
>   the response.

There is also a nice explanation in [this FAQ](http://faq.domainmonster.com/dns/glue_record/).

Answer (score 3):

I hope this is taken the right way, but have a good read at this, particularly the section on "Domain Name Space" (even more specifically, "Domain name formulation").

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System

It explains the way in which a name is resolved and way, way more.

Comment: Taken the right way, absolutely. I know I must read way more, but this question was itching. Thanks!

Comment: No bother, I try to avoid (in some cases) answering directly, because I (personally) learn looaaadss more trying to find the answers (when pointed in the right direction obviously!). Glad to help at least a little.